# Using Xamarin.Google.ARCore package in a Xamarin.Android project resulting in AndroidManifest.xml error

Tags: android, xamarin, android-manifest, arcore

I am referencing the Xamarin.Google.ARCore nuget package in a Xamarin project. But while building my Xamarin project, I am getting an error in the AndroidManifest.xml that's related to com.google.ar.core

```
2>------ Build started: Project: AndroidApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2> AndroidApp -> D:_builds_\AndroidApp\Debug_AnyCPU\Output\AndroidApp.dll
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2106,3): error AMM0000: D:\code\nx\AndroidApp......_builds_\AndroidApp\Debug_AnyCPU\AndroidApp\100\lp\22\jl\AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-54 Error:
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targ**ets(2106,3): error AMM0000: Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-54**
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2106,3): error AMM0000: D:\code\nx\AndroidApp......_builds_\AndroidApp\Debug_AnyCPU\AndroidApp\100\lp\22\jl\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
2>D : \code\nx\AndroidApp......_builds_\AndroidApp\Debug_AnyCPU\AndroidApp\100\lp\22\jl\AndroidManifest.xml error :
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2106,3): error AMM0000: Validation failed, exiting
```

Following is the AndroidManifest.xml generated by the build tools in the output folder..

[image]

Comment: It may help to see your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Added the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I referenced the Xamarin.Google.ARCore nuget package in a Xamarin.Android project with the Target Framework Android 11.0 and Android 12.0. I successfully build the project. So could you tell me the version of Target Framework Android you have used.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT The issue got resolved after updating the Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.11.7. The issue was happening with the Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.5.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after updating the Visual Studio 2019. The issue was coming in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 ( 16.5.1 version). I updated the Visual Studio 2019 to 16.11.7 version, and then reinstalled Xamarin by installing the 'Mobile development using .Net' package. Then the issue got resolved.